# Identifying a sequence as subset of subspace

Tags: sequences-and-series, elementary-set-theory, notation

If I have some sequence $\mathcal A = (a_i)$ of objects $a_i$ (maybe finite, maybe countably infinite) how can I say that those objects all exist in some subspace $S$?  Is it correct to say $\mathcal A \subseteq S$?  I'm not sure because $\mathcal A$ isn't a *set* it's a sequence.

Comment: A *sequence* of objects that are elements of $S$ is a function $f$ from $\mathbb N$ to $S$. A function is a *set* of couples; in this case : $f \subseteq \mathbb N \times S$.

Comment: Okay.  So I'd just say $\mathcal A \subseteq \Bbb N \times S$?  Thanks!

Comment: Functions abide by more rules than being a set of couples, in particular, they cannot map the same input to multiple outputs. i.e. if $(n,s)$ and $(n,s^\prime)$ are members of $f$, then $s=s^\prime$. So while it is true that $\mathcal{A} \subseteq \mathbb{N} \times S$, you haven't really conveyed that $\mathcal{A}$ is a sequence to the reader. You can assume the reader knows what functions and sequences are and simply use $(a_i) \in S^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: You can just say "where every $a_i\in S$". Or, "$(a_i)$ is a sequence of elements of $S$".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in your assertion that $(a_i)\subseteq S$ lacks some formality, but I think it would be understood as intended if you wrote it that way.

Here are some other options:

1. Use $(a_i) \in S^{\mathbb{N}}$ if you have a sequence in the usual sense.
2. Use $(a_i) \in S^N$ if you have a sequence of finite length.
3. Introduce $\{a_i\}\subseteq S$ and use the object $(a_i)$ when needed.